# MYSQL Isolation Level & SELECT FOR UPDATE

Tags: mysql, percona

I'm Using MySQL Server (Percona), i need to know if i'm correct on the following approach:
- Isolation Level User: READ_COMMITED
When starting transaction i would like to prevent any other users from reading the selected rows, currently i'm Using SELECT FROM TABLE WHERE ID = 10 FOR UPDATE, since ID Columns is Indexed, then i do update for the selected Rows.

- Is this approach will make sure that no other users will read the value of selected rows until i commit or rollback?

EXPLANATION:
User A: Sent order to lab with status = 0 & ORDER_ID = 10.
User B: Will accept the order, but in same time User A: Decided to cancel the order.

IF User B: Hit Save Button i will do SELECT FOR UPDATE WHERE ORDER_ID = 10, Is this will lock the User A from reading the ORDER_ID = 10 until user B: Commit or Rollback?

Comment: Statements which require an exclusive lock(`UPDATE,DELETE,INSERT,SELECT..FOR UPDATE`) will block until they can obtain the lock. The regular `SELECT`s will work as usual and will not see any changes made in the uncommited transaction.

Comment: OK, That good enough for me, since i have application work on network environment, there will be multiple users accessing the same record in some cases